# Emacs org-mode python blocks have 5 space tabs, but I want 4 space tabs

Tags: python, emacs, tabs, indentation, org-mode

I'm writing python code inside source blocks within an org-mode file; I'm editing
the code-block in a sub-buffer, in python mode using the emacs command `C-c '`

Example:

```
#+begin_src python
def function(x):
     hitting_tab_inserts_5_spaces=x*2
     if x<0:
          hitting_tab_inserts_5_spaces=-x
     return x
```

and I'm getting 5 space tabs everywhere, instead of the 4 space tabs that I want.

Note: I have viper (vim emulation) on.

Where in the configuration are the parameters that affect tabination inside codeblocks in org-mode files?

If I edit a `.py` file using emacs, I do get 4-space tabs; this 5-space tab thing is only happening inside org-mode.

Comment: If you add something like this to your `.emacs` file using an `org-mode-hook`, would that help?:  `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (setq indent-tabs-mode t) (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4)) (setq tab-width 4) (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)))`

Comment: @lawlist: Why don't you copy your comment into a reply so Dave can select it as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun my-tab-related-stuff ()
   (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
   (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4))
   (setq tab-width 4)
   (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-tab-related-stuff)
```

Comment: Why the choice of tab-stop-list 4 200 4?

Comment: @JonathanRayner -- the original poster of the question to this thread specified that he/she desired a spacing width of 4, so that is why I used 4.  I used 200 because it seemed to me that most users will not exceed the need such a large number of tab stops.

Comment: Sorry - that's my mistake, I skimmed over number-sequence and commented too hastily. Makes sense, thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: @lawlist When I start wrint into `#+begin_src ...#+end_src` block first line always starts with a tab. Would it be possible to start inner block without a indent? and also can we apply 4 space instead of tab?

Comment: @alper -- Inasmuch as this answer was written a little more than 6.5 years ago, and because most Emacs related stuff is handled nowadays on emacs.stackexchange.com, I would suggest writing up a new question over there.  A portion of your inquiry appears to be the same as a question of yours that was marked "duplicate" earlier today.  As such, when you write up your new question, be sure to include sufficient information such as why it is not a duplicate with respect to indentation / flush-left ...

Comment: @lawlist Please see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68129/org-mode-how-to-apply-4-spaces-for-tab-without-initial-indent-inside-source-code . Also I am sorry for keep asking too questions.